# how to properly append filename from database to src in video in React

Tags: reactjs

need to render a video in react but video does not appear. i have video filename stored in database and the actual video in server (inside the folder 'uploads' which is inside 'public')

this is my video component

```
<video ref={videoRef} onClick={onVideoPress} className='w-1/2 mx-auto'>
            <source src={`/../uploads/${course.video}`} type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

i tried this (a_videoUpload.mp4 from the 'uploads' folder) and it worked fine

```
<video ref={videoRef} onClick={onVideoPress} className='w-1/2 mx-auto'>
            <source src="/../uploads/a_videoUpload.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

this is the whole code

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

const CourseDetail = () => {
  const [course, setCourse] = useState({})
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false)
  const {id} = useParams()

  const videoRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/lesson/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        setCourse(response.data[0])  
      })
    
  },[id])

  const onVideoPress = () => {
    if(playing) {
        videoRef?.current?.pause()
        setPlaying(false)
    } else {
        videoRef?.current?.play()
        setPlaying(true)
    }
}

  return (
    <div className='w-8/12 bg-white mx-auto p-10 rounded-md shadow-md mt-10'>
        <h1 className='text-red-400 font-bold text-xl'>{course.title}</h1>
        <div className='w-8/12 bg-gray-900 mx-auto mt-10'>
          <video ref={videoRef} onClick={onVideoPress} className='w-1/2 mx-auto'>
            <source src={`/../uploads/${course.video}`} type="video/mp4" />
          </video>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CourseDetail
```

Comment: does `course.video` contains the filename in the correct format?

Comment: @Marios yes as one of them holds the value 'a_videoUpload.mp4'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer i changed:

```
<video ref={videoRef} onClick={onVideoPress} className='w-1/2 mx-auto'>
  <source src="/../uploads/a_videoUpload.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

to this:

```
<video ref={videoRef} onClick={onVideoPress} className='w-1/2 mx-auto' src=`/uploads/${course. Video}` />
```